# How we can set missing data(NA) in R?

Tags: r, data-mining

I have two sets, training set and test set that there are some values that they are NA, I need a code or a guidance in R language that set values for NA.
Thank you....

Comment: Please read it before asking a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you trying to impute the NA values?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked in subsequent comments if you can replace NA's with values other than zeros. You can. One method is mean imputation (The following code is reproduced from r bloggers:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:20, y = c(1:10,rep(NA,10)))
df$y[is.na(df$y)] = mean(df$y, na.rm=TRUE)
```

It is important that you understand whether mean imputation is appropriate for your data (or any other imputation for that manner) [short blog post on problems with mean imputation](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/mean-imputation/)

Just use caution.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(NA, 1:5),10, replace = T))

  a
  5
  5
  3
  2
 NA
  5
  1
 NA
  5
  4
```

Now replace the NA with any value. Please note that in this case I replace all `NA's` with `0`

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

**Result**

```
 a
 5
 5
 3
 2
 0
 5
 1
 0
 5
 4
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a question. can I set these with another values not with 0?

Comment: @parisan you can simply replace 0 with anything you want.